# Word / Excel crashing when looping through Access database QueryDefs

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-word, dao

I have a VBA procedure in Word that checks to see if a QueryDef exists in an Access database.  It was working fine until a few days ago, when it started crashing Word.

The issue seems to be this line:  `For Each qdf In db.QueryDefs`.  This is the line on which Word hangs and then crashes.  I don't think it's my code because I have created a very basic test procedure in a new Word document that is just a loop with nothing in it (see below) and created a new Access database and it still crashes.

A connection to the database is successfully made as I get the locked database file.  And this code will successfully execute and print to immediate window:   `Debug.Print db.QueryDefs.Count`

I also tested this basic procedure with the empty loop in Excel and it crashes there too.  I also updated Office (I'm on Office 365, desktop version of Office).  Is there something I'm missing?

`Reference to:  Microsoft Office 16.0 Access Database Engine Object Library`

```
Option Explicit


Sub Test()

    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim db  As DAO.Database

    Set db = OpenDatabase("DatabasePathAndFileName")  

    Debug.Print db.QueryDefs.Count

    For Each qdf In db.QueryDefs

    Next qdf

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hit F9 as you step through the code and post back with the exact error.  Also, have you restarted the machine recently?  I have seen CTRL-Breaks build up over time, and cause all kinds of weirdness, but a restart usually fixes everything.    Finally, what changed since it was working last??!!

Try this.  What happens?

```
Public Sub ExecParameterQuery()

    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("myActionQuery")

    'Set the value of the QueryDef's parameter
    qdf.Parameters("Organization").Value = "Microsoft"

    'Execute the query
    qdf.Execute dbFailOnError

    'Clean up
    qdf.Close
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, I rebooted.  Hitting F9 is how I found out what line it was crashing on.  There is no error. When I got F9 to execute the loop, word hangs and then crashers. As far as I know, nothing has changed.

Comment: I just added something to my original answer.

Comment: I tried your code and I am getting the error "Item not found in this collection" on the line `Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("myActionQuery")`

Comment: I modified the code to add a QueryDef to the database and then add a record to the database using the QueryDef I created.  All of that works fine.  I only have a problem when I try to loop through the QueryDefs.  Word crashes on the `For Each` line when I attempt a loop.

Comment: Doesn't make sense.  You can try to repair Office through the Control Panel.  Also, make sure you have any/all Office updates downloaded and installed.

Comment: I had the same thought.  I did both of those things and also uninstalled and reinstalled Office.  None of those things fixed the problem.

Comment: Arggghhh!  I'm out of ideas.  Hopefully someone else will jump in here with a solution sometime soon.  If not, re-frame your question, and post back here in a couple days.  Someone out there may have encountered this issue at some time in the past, and maybe that person knows how to fix this.  There is always a reason for everything.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for the time you've spent trying to help me.  Posting back in a few days is good advice and I'll do that if I don't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try stepping through the collection to see if it is a specific query that causes the problem:

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim db  As DAO.Database

    Set db = OpenDatabase("DatabasePathAndFileName") 

    If db.QueryDefs.Count > 0 Then 
        For Each qdf In db.QueryDefs
            MsgBox qdf.Name
        Next qdf
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: There are no queries in my test database.  My original database had queries, though.  However, I can't get to the `MsgBox` line because Word hangs and then crashes on the `For Each` line

Comment: Then check for that. If no queries, there is nothing to loop. See edited answer, please.